# Valid XML unicode characters

Tags: java, xml, unicode

I am getting this error :

```
com.ctc.wstx.exc.wstxlazyexception illegal character entity expansion character code 0xd83d
```

I researched for the code `0xd83d` and the corresponding html is `&#55357;` �

Is this character allowed in an XML?
How can I check it?

Comment: It is not allowed.  See first duplicate link for the allowed ranges of Unicode characters.

Comment: The code in question doesn't represent a character, it represents one half of a surrogate pair. Astral characters (such as emoji) should be represented by a single character entity reference, they can't be split into a surrogate pair each with its own reference.